# Bing ads Campaign Management

Tags: java, bing, bing-ads-api

I have recently started playing with the Bing Ads api for managing my ads and campaigns and I am having problem in authenticating user (not oauth authentication).

I authenticated my user using oauth by the following

```
private String devToken = "ZZZZZ";
private String clientId = "AAA0BBB-XXXX-AAAAA";
protected static String UserName = "a.v@h.c";
protected static String Password = "********";

// To get the initial access and refresh tokens you must call requestAccessAndRefreshTokens with the authorization redirection URL.
OAuthTokens tokens = oAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant.requestAccessAndRefreshTokens(url);

System.out.println("Access token: " + tokens.getAccessToken());
System.out.println("Refresh token: " + tokens.getRefreshToken());

authorizationData = new AuthorizationData();
authorizationData.setDeveloperToken(getDevToken());
authorizationData.setAuthentication(oAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant);
```

This authenticates my user just fine since I can use the `ICustomerManagementService.class` just fine for accounts related information

```
customerServiceClient = new ServiceClient<>(authorizationData, ICustomerManagementService.class);
ArrayOfAccount accounts = searchAccountsByUserId(user.getId());
```

The above works perfectly. But when I try to do the same with `ICampaignManagementService.class` like below

```
campaignServiceClient = new ServiceClient<>(authorizationData, ICampaignManagementService.class);
GetAdsByAdGroupIdRequest cReq = new GetAdsByAdGroupIdRequest();
cReq.setAdGroupId(1234567890L);
campaignServiceClient.getService().getAdsByAdGroupId(cReq);
```

I get error code 106 saying that the user is not authorized.

```
The user does not represent a authorized developer.
106
```

Any help in this regard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to set the CustomerId and CustomerAccountId header elements (CustomerId and AccountId of AuthorizationData). These headers are not available with the Customer Management service, but are applicable for Campaign Management service. If that does not resolve the issue please feel free to send the SOAP request + response to [support](https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/bing-ads-support) for investigation. I hope this helps!